# How to see the value of an element in a char array in WinDBG?

Tags: .net, char, windbg

The first command shows me the elements of the array in a memory dump of a net process. When I try see the actual character stored in each element at index 0 using the second command, it fails. For example, if the array contained 'f', 'o', 'o' as the first three characters, I want a command that shows 'f' on the screen.

```
0:000> !da -length 3 0000000001f11af8 
Name: System.Char[]
MethodTable: 000007fef77e9688
EEClass: 000007fef73eef58
Size: 74(0x4a) bytes
Array: Rank 1, Number of elements 25, Type Char
Element Methodtable: 000007fef77e97d8
[0] 0000000001f11b08
[1] 0000000001f11b0a
[2] 0000000001f11b0c

0:000> !do 0000000001f11b08
<Note: this object has an invalid CLASS field>
Invalid object
```

Comment: As @Dono mentioned, those array elements are value types. Since the diff between each address is two bytes, then my guess is that each element is a unicode character. Try experimenting with `du`, `dw`, and `dW` on those element addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sos.dumpobj` is used to dump managed objects, or more specifically things that extend (directly or indirectly) from System.Object. A char (or System.Char) is a valuetype, which extends from System.ValueType, not System.Object.

To dump a valuetype, you may use the command `!sos.dumpvc <MT> <address>`. The MT (method table) is given above as 000007fef77e97d8, so to dump each of the values, you would do the following:

```
!sos.dumpvc 000007fef77e97d8 0000000001f11b08
!sos.dumpvc 000007fef77e97d8 0000000001f11b0a
!sos.dumpvc 000007fef77e97d8 0000000001f11b0c
```

This will result in something like the following:

```
Name: System.Char
MethodTable 000007fef77e97d8
EEClass: 000007feea37f018
Size: 24(0x18) bytes
(C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll)
Fields:
             MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007fef77e97d8 400021e        0          System.Char  1 instance               66 m_value
```

The value 66 is the hexadecimal value of 'f'. Also notice the VT column. This indicates that this is a value type.

A smarter option is `sosex.mdt`. If you do not have SOSEX, you can get it [here](http://www.stevestechspot.com/). Among the many options, the -e argument expands a collection type (such as an array) by however many levels specified. You would use it as `sosex.mdt -e:1 <address>`. The address in this case would be of the array, or 0000000001f11af8. The output would look something like this:

```
!sosex.mdt -e:1 0000000001f11af8
0000000001f11af8(System.Char[], Elements: 3)
[0] 'f'
[1] 'o'
[2] 'o'
```